# Plugins and frameworks for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, visual-c++, phpmyadmin

I am developing a database application which holds the information of all Banks in Germany. I developed the database using PhpMyAdmin and I'm going to use Word Press to create the UI. Is there a **plugin** that can be used with word press to easily integrate the UI with the database. Something which also allows to easily update the database. Are there any existing **frameworks** that can be used for the same purpose? How about using **Visual C++** for easily integrating and updating the SQL table? Basically, I just want an easy way or a short cut to connect the back end to the UI and get it done in a short period of time. Thank you.

Comment: I think wordpress is not the best choice for this kind of application... Maybe you better try with something different, like Laravel...

Comment: @DaFois Thank you for your answer. But, I will have to go ahead with wordpress due to some contraints. I think using the plugin 'wpDataTables' for wordpress will get the work done. :)